# How to Rename App name on TestFlight?

Tags: testflight

Is it possible to rename an iOS app on TestFlight?  The only way I see that's possible is to remove the app (and all its associated builds) and add a new one.

Comment: What happens when you upload a new version with a new name (but the same bundle id)?

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but this requirement came up today for one of our apps and thought to leave the solution for anybody who wants it.

You just need to change the Application Name in your app and upload a new build and the new name will reflect in TestFlight.

Comment: you mean to say that if we only change app name in our plist etc (and don't change bundle id and any thing on itunes) & upload the build, our app name on itunes will automatically change... OR is it only the case with testflight? I'm confused. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This does not apply to TestFlight anymore since Apple has bought it and now you can manage the app details from the iTunes Connect panel.

Comment: @MohibSheth Do you know how to do this now that Apple has bought TestFlight?

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had a requirement on this. I have changed the AppName in **App Information** section.

[image]

Comment: @Llama Yes It's Not. It's in Appstoreconnect>>Apps>>YourApp>App Information. If you will change here then it will reflect in Testflight.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if Test-flight would allows to rename the uploaded API as they have to maintain incremental build versions.

Researched a lot on this, yet Test-flight have not documented it anywhere!